# probleme with vps connection device

Tags: vpn, connection, vps

I bought a VPS with Ubuntu and I installed VNC and I would like to use a VPN account to change my IP address when I want. I have set up OpenVPN and configuration, but when I click on my VPN account nothing works. I have always my original IP address. The images below mey help explain my situation:

[image: Original picture here:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgsf3.png)]

[image: Original picture here:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hgis.png)]

Do you have a solution to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your OpenVPN configuration was not correct and your VPN is not connecting.

See your log file for connection fault